# Mostrar alerta después de recargar página con Bootstrap validator y ajax

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, bootstrap

Tengo un formulario con HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="#!" method="post" id="form-new-role">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
      <label class="control-label">Nombre</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="25" id="role-name" name="role_name" required="required"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
      <label class="control-label" >Descripci&oacute;n</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="role-descrip" name="role_descrip" >
    </div>
      <p class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-raised btn-sm" id="btn-new-role"> Guardar </button>
      </p>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hago una validación con Bootstrap validator:

```
function validFrmRole(){

    $('#form-new-role').bootstrapValidator({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    live: 'enabled',
      fields: {
        'role_name': {
          validators: {
            stringLength: {
              min: 5,
              message: 'El nombre debe contener mínimo 5 y máximo 25 caracteres'
                    },
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Por favor ingrese el nombre del rol'
            }
          }
        },
        'role_descrip': {
          validators: {
            stringLength: {
              max: 100,
              message: 'El nombre debe contener máximo 100 caracteres'
            },
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Por favor ingrese la descripción del rol'
            }
          }
            }
        },onSuccess: function(e, data) {

                insertRole();
        }
    });
}
```

Si la validación se hizo correctamente, se ejecuta la función insertRole(), el cual mediante ajax envía los datos recogidos del formulario a un us script php que realiza una inserción a MySQL, y dependiente del valor retornado se debe mostrar un mensaje: "Actualización exitosa" o "Error al registrar rol".
Mi problema es que no logró mostrar al usuario el mensaje porque la página se actualiza inmediantamente después de:

```
onSuccess: function(e, data) {

                    insertRole();
            }
```

¿Alguien me puede dar una idea de como hacer que se muestre alerta?

Función insertRole():

```
    function insertRole(){
    role_name=$('#role-name').val();
    role_descrip=$('#role-descrip').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: './controllers/insert-role.php',
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        data: 'role_name=' + role_name + '&role_descrip=' + role_descrip,
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(r){

        if(r==1){

                alertify.success("Registro exitoso");

            }else{

                alertify.error("Error al registrar");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Script PHP:

```
$role_name = $_POST['role_name'];
$role_descrip = $_POST['role_descrip'];


$new_query = new Query();
$new_query->insertRole($role_name, $role_descrip);
```

Función PHP:

```
class Query{
  public function insertRole($user_id, $status_id, $role_name, $role_descrip, $reg_date){
  $model = new Connection();
  $conexion = $model->connectionDb();
  try {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO TROL (nombre, descrip)
            VALUES ( :nombre, :descrip)';
    $statment = $conexion->prepare($sql);

    $statment->bindParam(':nombre', $role_name);
    $statment->bindParam(':descrip', $role_descrip);

      if ($statment->execute()) {        
        echo  $result = 1;

      }else {
        echo $result = 0;

      }
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
  }
}
}
```